# Real-world applications of zygohistomorphic prepromorphisms

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory

Yes, [these ones](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Zygohistomorphic_prepromorphisms):

```
{-#LANGUAGE TypeOperators, RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Morphism.Zygo
import Control.Morphism.Prepro
import Control.Morphism.Histo
import Control.Functor.Algebra
import Control.Functor.Extras
import Control.Functor.Fix
import Control.Comonad.Cofree

zygohistomorphic_prepromorphism 
  :: Functor f
  => Algebra f b
  -> GAlgebra f (ZygoT (Cofree f) b) a 
  -> (f :~> f) 
  -> FixF f 
  -> a
zygohistomorphic_prepromorphism f 
  = g_prepro (distZygoT (liftAlgebra f) (distHisto id))
```

Yes, I know that they're a ([HHOS](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/ha-ha-only-serious.html)) joke. I'm looking for a real-world example for simple hack value and last, but not least, to add it to the wiki saying "This is the idiomatic way to express XYZ". I *will* put a bounty on this should you fail to come up with a solution. If you're completely lost on what they're about, Edward posted a [short explanation](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/6ml1y/a_pretty_useful_haskell_snippet/c04ako5) on reddit.

Eligible Answers must:

1. do something at least remotely and theoretically computationally useful. That is, answers that reduce to `id` are out.
2. use all the features of the scheme, no passing in of id, or const, or equivalent.
3. not equally well be expressible by a simple, vanilla fold or such, so don't merely implement `product` in a meandering way.

Bonus points will be given to:

- Well-known problem or algorithm
- solved, respectively expressed, in an unusual way that gains
- clarity and/or performance
- and/or hack value
- and/or lulz, in roughly that order, as well as
- high-ranking answers (yay democracy)

Please also note [Edward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057136/real-world-applications-of-zygohistomorphic-prepromorphisms/5058725#5058725) below. What ZHPM implementation you use is your choice.

Comment: If you had included `IO` in your stack, we could have used SimonPJ's famous `launchMissles` function. But I guess the whole point of all that super-pure abstract nonsense is to avoid the possibility of such things.

Comment: Well, `a` can be anything, so feel free to construct an IO value that strategically launches missiles based on an assessment of your input data.

Comment: I clicked on this question because I had no idea what the hell you're talking about. +1 good sir, +1

Comment: Someone looking to use all of the components would do well to manually write out what a zygohistomorphic prepromorphism recursion expands to, and then look for problems that need all of these patterns; imperative loops tend to do arbitrarily complicated tracking, so they might be a good place to look.

Comment: and more important - Will it blend ?! (very sorry, couldnt resist)

Comment: Should I feel stupid for not understanding what all this is about? :D

Answer (score 56):

Sharon Curtis and Shin-Cheng Mu have a Functional Pearl using zygomorphisms to find maximally dense segments (a generalization of maximum segment sums). Zygomorphisms are seemingly a good fit for sliding window problems once you are accustomed to them.

http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/~scm/2010/functional-pearl-maximally-dense-segments/

I'd nominate the authors for extra credit as they've avoided the use of the fixed-point Mu functor.

Comment: From skimming, I think I see how they use histo when tracking the DRSP (in the same sense that a simple `foldr` can look at the list it already constructed), but the prepro isn't immediately apparent to me. Could you elaborate? (and, if possible, give short+sweet code we can tack onto the wiki page?)

Comment: The code is available from a link below the errata on the landing page. The actual definition of the zygomorphism is in the file Main.hs - its different to the definition in the paper. It is "just" a zygomorphism not a "zygohistomorphic prepromorphisms" - a zygomorphism is the closest thing I've seen with a real world use. Though there are  slides by Jevgeni Kabanov using histomorphisms for dynamic programming: 
http://www.cs.ioc.ee/~tarmo/tday-viinistu/kabanov-slides.pdf

Answer (score 41):

Note, the signature of these has changed, because it was insufficiently general, and I included it (as a joke) in my [recursion-schemes](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/recursion-schemes/0.4.0.3/doc/html/Data-Functor-Foldable.html) package.

```
zygoHistoPrepro 
  :: (Unfoldable t, Foldable t) 
  => (Base t b -> b) 
  -> (forall c. Base t c -> Base t c) 
  -> (Base t (EnvT b (Stream (Base t)) a) -> a) 
  -> t
  -> a
```

The implementation was simplified as well.

```
zygoHistoPrepro f = gprepro (distZygoT f distHisto)
```

And from the new implementation it should be obvious how to implement a *generalized* zygohistomorphic prepromorphism, by relaxing the constraint that you have a `(Base t)-Branching` stream, through the use of `distGHisto` instead.

Comment: Ah yes quite obvious.